# How can Lua as imperative programming language be used for functional programming

Tags: lua

The documentation says that Lua can be used for `functional` programming but also that it is an `imperative` programming language. So for all the posts I have read about `imperative` and `functional` programming they all said the same:

`Functional` programming relies on a `declarative` programming language. This [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/functional-programming-vs-imperative-programming) shows a table that compares characteristics of `imperative` and `functional` programming and these are two completely different approaches to solve problems.

So how can I realise a `functional` solution for a problem when I use an `imperative` programming language?

Comment: Lua supports both imperative and functional programming approaches.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes I read that, but for me these two are opposites. It might be that I did not understand it the right way, but "in my head" a programming language is either imperative or declarative, not both

Comment: Hot water and cold water are two opposites. Basin faucet mixer can provide both hot and cold water for you.  There is no contradiction here.  Think of Lua as a water mixer.

Comment: Older versions of Lua have example programs in the test folder, including functional-style ones. Try factorial.lua in  https://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.5.tar.gz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best source will be “A Taste of Functional Programming” on p.74 of the newest, 4th edition of [*Programming in Lua*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8590379868). There, the creator of Lua adopts an example from the research report *Haskell vs. Ada vs. C++ vs. Awk vs. ... An Experiment in Software Prototyping Productivity*, by Paul Hudak and Mark P. Jones.

The point is, Lua provides the mechanisms by which to write programs using functional programming patterns and constructs. As said [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), functional programming is a programming paradigm. A style. So, some programming languages are built for that paradigm exclusively. Others, like Lua, offer a variety of programming mechanisms.